# Scheduled powershell script run by system does not run in foreground

Tags: powershell, scripting, windows-10, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to schedule a script to run when I'm not present at my computer. The script has to run with administrator rights AND run in the foreground so that I can see any message or window that is created when I get back to the computer.

The problem is that scheduled system scripts run in the background, this resulting in no visible window or console to show me any results.

here is the command i use to create my scheduled task (using powershell):

```
SchTasks /Create /SC ONIDLE /I 1 /TN MyScheduledTask /TR "Powershell scheduler.ps1" /RU "System"
```

All I need is some way to make some (or all if that's easier) of the commands in the script to become visible in the foreground to the user.

Thanks for any feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running scheduled tasks under the system account, they will run in the background.

You are running the task under System, `/RU "System"` use `/RU` with your username and `/RP` for your user password.

Please also take a look at this question: [Powershell Task Scheduler Stuck Running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45110750/powershell-task-scheduler-stuck-running/45119113#45119113)